# What is the intuition behind the Population Stability Index?

Tags: distributions, intuition, kullback-leibler, likelihood

The "Population Stability Index" for two distributions $P$ and $Q$ is defined as the  [Symmetrised Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Symmetrised_divergence):

$$
\mathrm{PSI}(P,Q) = D_{KL}(P||Q) + D_{KL}(Q||P) = \sum_i(P_i-Q_i)\log\frac{P_i}{Q_i}
$$

**What is the *intuition* behind this number?**

One can always use the intuition for $D_{KL}$ and say that PSI is

> *the expected number of extra bits required to code samples from $P$ using a code optimized for $Q$ rather than the code optimized for $P$*
>
> **plus** *the expected number of extra bits required to code samples from $Q$ using a code optimized for $P$ rather than the code optimized for $Q$,*

but this is quite a mouthful.

[Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-population-stability-index) and [UCAnalytics](http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/population-stability-index-psi-banking-case-study/) offer this "interpretation":

- PSI < 0.1: Insignificant change (*No action required*)
- 0.1 < PSI < 0.25: Some minor change (*Start worrying*)
- 0.25 < PSI: Major shift in population (*Need to delve deeper*)

what is the basis for this?

Comment: Can you give some "more formal" reference that defines and uses/explains the PSI? Never heard the term

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: I wish I had something better than the 3(three!) links in the text.

Comment: This link seems to be useful:  http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/288-2010.pdf

Comment: I haven't checked that but the original source for these commonly used thresholds is: "An introduction to credit scoring" by E.M. Lewis

Comment: I would like to add a link to my dissertation that I recently completed. Please comment on the content and I hope it helps to understand PSI better.
https://scholarworks.wmich.edu/dissertations/3208

Answer (score 7):

## Intuition

Kullback-Leibler Divergence [can be interpreted to mean](https://www.countbayesie.com/blog/2017/5/9/kullback-leibler-divergence-explained)

> how many bits of information we expect to lose is we use $Q$ instead of $P$.

Thus the Population Stability Index is the "*roundtrip loss*":

> how many bits of information we expect to lose is we use $Q$ instead of $P$ and then use that again to go back to $Q$.

## Values

It appears that the Population Stability Index is closely related to the [G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test):

$$
\mathrm{PSI}(P,Q) = \frac{G(P,Q) + G(Q,P)}{2N}
$$

where $N$ is the total number of observations.
(and thus can be computed using [`scipy.stats.power_divergence`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.power_divergence.html), as well as directly using [`scipy.stats.entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html)).

Since $G\sim\chi^2_{N-1}$ and $G(P,Q)$ and $G(Q,P)$ are highly correlated, we
can assume that $N\times\mathrm{PSI}\sim\chi^2_{N-1}$
(if they were independent instead, [we would have had](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096298/37092) $2N\times\mathrm{PSI}\sim\chi^2_{2N-2}$).

Therefore the p-values corresponding to `PSI` can be computed like this:

```py
import scipy.stats as st
import pandas as pd

def psi_p_value_correlated(psi, n):
    "chi2 p-value for PSI assuming G(P,Q) and G(Q,P) are highly correlated"
    return st.distributions.chi2.sf(n*psi,n-1)

def psi_p_value_independent(psi, n):
    "chi2 p-value for PSI assuming G(P,Q) and G(Q,P) are independent"
    return st.distributions.chi2.sf(2*n*psi,2*(n-1))

def psi_p_values(p_value, psis=(0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5), ns=(2, 3, 5, 8, 13)):
    return pd.DataFrame({"N":f"{N=}", **{f"{PSI=:.2f}":p_value(PSI, N) for PSI in psis}}
                        for N in ns).set_index("N", verify_integrity=True)

psi_p_values(psi_p_value_correlated)
       PSI=0.05  PSI=0.10  PSI=0.25  PSI=0.50
 N=2   0.751830  0.654721  0.479500  0.317311
 N=3   0.927743  0.860708  0.687289  0.472367
 N=5   0.992809  0.973501  0.869800  0.644636
 N=8   0.999737  0.997444  0.959840  0.779777
 N=13  0.999999  0.999940  0.993507  0.888813

psi_p_values(psi_p_value_independent)
       PSI=0.05  PSI=0.10  PSI=0.25  PSI=0.50
 N=2   0.904837  0.818731  0.606531  0.367879
 N=3   0.989814  0.963064  0.826641  0.557825
 N=5   0.999867  0.998248  0.961731  0.757576
 N=8   1.000000  0.999979  0.995466  0.889326
 N=13  1.000000  1.000000  0.999851  0.966120
```

This means that `PSI=0.1` with `N=3` is due to chance with probability 86%
(assuming $G(P,Q)$ and $G(Q,P)$ are highly correlated).

PS. Interestingly enough, the official "interpretation" of the `PSI` value completely ignores $N$.

Comment: `PSI` can also be computed using `scipy.stats.entropy`. Like so `PSI(A, B) = entropy(A, B) + entropy(B, A)`. See here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on OP's question "*what is the basis for this*"?  Why the associated $p$-values indicate "insignificant/minor/major" changes? (What I saw is, no matter what `DF` is, no entries are below the conventional 0.05 threshold).