# Symmetrization of the G-test statistic?

Tags: chi-squared-test, kullback-leibler

[G-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) statistic is defined as

$$
G(O,E) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^N O_i \ln \frac{O_i}{E_i}
$$

and $G \sim \chi^2_{N-1}$ asymptotically.

**How is
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& G(O,E)+G(E,O) \\
  &=& 2N\big(D_{KL}(O||E)+D_{KL}(E||O)\big) \\
  &=& 2\sum_i(O_i-E_i)(\ln O_i - \ln E_i)
\end{eqnarray}
$$ distributed?**

If $G(O,E)$ and $G(E,O)$ are **independent**, [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096298/37092) $S\sim\chi^2_{2N-2}$.
However, it is dubious that they are...

(See [What is the intuition behind the Population Stability Index?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/219822/13538))

Comment: Note that $S = 2 \sum_i  (O_i-E_i) \log (\frac{O_i}{E_i})$ or equivalently $2 \sum_i  (O_i-E_i) (\log O_i -\log E_i)$. Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Because $G(E,O)$ does not even have an expectation (indeed, it's not even a fully defined random variable), this formulation is dubious.  One could make progress by stating specific asymptotic conditions: we would like the $E_i$ to increase uniformly (without bound), for instance.

Comment: @whuber: your condition - **both** $\lim E_i=\infty$ **and** $\lim O_i=\infty$ - is reasonable. What can be said then? Thank you.